# Getting attribute value through constant variable - JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

In my project, I set up the `Constant` class like this

```
class Constant {
    public static final String PARA = "para";

    public Integer getPARA () {
        return PARA;
    }
}
```

in order to access the constant from the jsp through `el`

```
<!-- test.jsp -->
<jsp:useBean id="cons" class="com.test.Constant" scope="session"/>

...
${cons.PARA}
```

Now, in my java code, I set an attribute for that constant

```
// foo.java
request.setAttribute(Constant.PARA, "this is a param");
```

To access that attribute in the jsp, we could do  `${para}` but how can I access the attribute value ("this is a param") through that constant variable `cons.PARAM` ? In short, how can we convert the following code into jstl ?

```
<%=request.getAttribute(Constant.PARA)%>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found out 1 way to do it

```
<c:set var='param' value="${cons.PARA}" />

<c:out value="${requestScope[param] }" />
```

Comment: That's the right way to do it. You can do it in one line with `<c:out value="${requestScope[cons.PARA]}" />`

Comment: yup, I just figured out as well :D